# Simple Lisp Loop

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun add-them(a b)

    (loop
        (if(< a 15)
           (setq a (* a b))
           (write a)
        )
        (when(> a 15)
            
            (return a))
    
    )

)
(print (add-them 3 5))
```

Having issues with this code block I want to be able to check if `a` is less than 15 and multiply it by `b` if it is less than 15 in a loop. Then I want to return it if it is greater than 15. I've never used lisp before and this is for an assignment so please do not outright give me the answer, just guidance.

Comment: Does your assignment require that you use a loop?

Comment: The assignment specifies "This is done repeatedly
as long as the result is less than 15."

Comment: So it does *not* require a loop; it can be done via recursion.

Comment: What should happen if a=15?

Comment: I'm assuming they want if >= 15 then return. It doesn't outright specify, so I'm guessing based on context.

Comment: I just realized this is already solved haha, it stopped at 15 because it was 15, I feel kind of dumb.

Comment: Please add exact instructions for this assignment (are you really required to output `a` in each step?)... and also ask the teacher whether you can use stuff like `loop` or just recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your syntax. The `if` statement takes three arguments: the condition, the code when the condition is true and the code when the condition is false.

```
(if <test>
  <do-this-when-true>
  <do-this-when-false> )
```

Each one of these must be a list, so if you need to do multiple things surround it with e.g. `progn`.
In your example it will look like this

```
(loop
        (if (< a 15)
           (progn
             (setq a (* a b))
             (write a))
           (return a))
    )
```

As mentioned in another comment, this is not very lispy but it should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no purpose in learning Lisp if you end up just replicating code that could have been written in Fortran.  It's better to think about a different way to solve the problem.  In particular this way:

To answer the assignment:

- start with a and b:

  - if a >= 15 the answer is a,
  - otherwise answer the assignment with a * b and b.